# have deleted the shared memory but get shm ipc_id error

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I have the code

```
shmid = shmget(IPC_CREAT, size, IPC_CREAT|0666) ;
if ( shmid < 0 )
{
        perror("get shm ipc_id error") ;
        return -1 ;
}
shmaddr = (unsigned int*)shmat(shmid, 0, 0 ) ;
```

create a shared memory and do something

int the bottom

```
  shmdt( shmaddr ) ;
  shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL) ;
```

to delete the share memory.

First time to execute the program, it works fine.

But if I execute the second time, it printf

```
get shm ipc_id error: Invalid argument
```

and I cannot figure out why it happen?

I have deleted and detach the shared memory, why it still happen?

And how to prevent it?

Comment: Note that the key is invalid (first argument of `shmget`). You probably wanted to use `IPC_PRIVATE`. See [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to man shmget:

```
ERRORS
       On failure, errno is set to one of the following:

       EINVAL A new segment was to be created and size < SHMMIN or size > SHMMAX, or  no  new  segment
              was  to  be created, a segment with given key existed, but size is greater than the size
              of that segment.
```

With `ipcs`, you can check if the delete succeeded or not.